# How do I remove this white "corrosion" from my lens ring?

Tags: lens, cleaning

I've purchased a new Sigma lens recently and everything is great about it except some white "corrosion" around the lens ring. Is it possible to safely remove it and restore the original look of the lens?

[image]

Comment: Looks like sun screen to me...

Comment: Usually sweat and skin oil that has trapped microscopic skin dander.

Answer (score 3):

I remove rubber rings from the lens and wash them in warm soapy water. They'll stretch enough to pull them off, just try not to stretch them any more than is absolutely required so that they will fit snugly when you put them back on after cleaning. Be sure to let them completely dry before reinstalling them on your lens.

Sometimes an old toothbrush or similar tool helps to get the crud out of the grooves. If the buildup is especially stubborn, I sometimes use lens cleaner fluid as well.

Third party [replacement rings](https://www.ebay.com/itm/325117488563) are also usually fairly inexpensive.

Comment: I’ve searched for “how to remove rubber ring” on YouTube and Google but can’t find a good example. Am I using the wrong keywords? I was hoping to see a video before doing it myself.

Comment: Just use a thin, flat object such as one of those things for opening the microSD card/SIM card drawer on a smart phone or one side of a pair of tweezers to raise the edge of the rubber a little in one spot. Pull it back a bit so that a quarter inch or so is out of the channel for the ring. Work your way around the entire ring until the edge all the way around is about 1/4" back, then repeat another 1/4" all the way around again and again until you have the ring far enough back that it is loose on the narrower part of the lens barrel and can slip right off the back of the lens.

Comment: Some people roll them inside out. With your lens you would take the front edge and pull it back over the rest of the ring until the entire ring is inside out and behind the channel in the lens barrel for the ring. You can see one half rolled back in this [lensrentals blog - about 3/4 way down when showing the 70-200mm non-IS lens](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/05/a-few-easy-lens-dustings/)